# <add text> placeholders disappear sporadically in Experience Manager

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, 2013-sp1

I have a multi-value embedded schema field with 4 subfields: subheading, text, image and caption, all of which are optional. Even if there is no field value, my template writes out the XPM markup to ensure that I get the `<add text>` placeholder, which can be clicked to add a value.

The placeholders do not appear until I click on a field which does have a value, which is fine, but as soon as I take an action which updates the preview (for example adding/changing an image, or clicking Update Preview) the placeholders disappear and do not come back even if I click on a field value.

The only way I have found to get them back is to click on the page in the breadcrumb and then back into an existing field value. Has anyone else seen this behaviour (for normal or embedded fields) and/or knows of a way to get the placeholders appearing consistently?

Comment: I have logged this with Customer Support and will update as and when I hear more

Answer (score 6):

What we do in our projects is using a text label ("empty" or something similar) between the span tags; that way, you always have a placeholder to click on.

Comment: Interesting and useful tip--that could be done by template's looking for empty values, defaults in schemas, or defaults in prototypes (default or custom Content types).